# Get closest input value on button click

Tags: google-tag-manager

In Google Tag Manager, I am trying to get the value from a hidden input field that is closest to the button that was clicked. I've tried a few different things, but it refuses to get the value.

This is the current code I am trying to use:

```
function(){
 return {{Click Element}}.closest('#st-signup-source').value;
}
```

[image]

I also tried these instructions, and it continued to return "undefined".

https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/capturing-the-correct-element-in-google-tag-manager/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting it to work, using the instructions from here:

https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/capturing-the-correct-element-in-google-tag-manager/

However, I had to modify the {{Find Closest}} Custom JavaScript Variable to look like this:

```
function(){
  return function(target, selector) {
    while (!target.matches(selector) && !target.matches('body')) {
      while (target.previousElementSibling!==null && !target.matches(selector)) {
        target = target.previousElementSibling;
      }
      target = !target.matches(selector) ? target.parentElement : target;
    }
    return target.matches(selector) ? target : undefined;
  }
}
```